# Next.js and multiple module.exports options in next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-images

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right for combining:

```
module.exports = withImages()
```

and

```
trailingSlash: true
```

within `next.config.js`.

My current file works:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')

module.exports = withImages()
```

... but when I try to add the `trailingSlash` key/value it throws up errors on building because obviously I'm not getting the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out as I wrote ... d'oh ... will leave answer in case it hurts someone else's brain:

```js
module.exports = withImages({
  trailingSlash: true
})
```